# Relative path in web service for deployment

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, publishing

My web service hosted on IIS cannot find a file in the same directory as the published bin folder(on localhost). It appears it is looking elsewhere for the file. How can I make it find the file using relative path so that it will work if I deploy to any web server.

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\DataStore.xml'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationphysicalpath.aspx) or Environment.CurrentDirectory or AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory